# grabbing data sets from a file with an arbitrary amount of spaces

Tags: c++, ofstream

**No direct answers or code examples please, this is my homework which i need to learn from. I'm looking for help concerning the algorithm i need to develop.

I seem to be having a logic error in coming up with a solution for a portion of my class work, the program involves multiple files, but here is the only relevant portion:

I have a file PlayerStats that holds the stats for a basketball player in:

- rebounds
- points
- assists
- uniform #

my initial reaction would be to create a while loop and read these into a temporary struct that holds these values, then create a merge function that merges the values of the temp struct with the inital array of records, simple enough?

```
struct Baller
{
   //other information on baller
   int rebounds;
   int assists;
   int uniform;
   int points;
   void merge(Baller tmp); //merge the data with the array of records
}

//in my read function..
Baller tmp; 
int j = 0;
inFile << tmp.uniform << tmp.assists << tmp.points << tmp.rebounds
while(inFile){
    ArrayRecords[j].merge(tmp);
    j++;
    //read in from infile again
}
```

**The catch**:
The file can have an arbitrary number of spaces between the identifiers, and the information can be in **any** order(leaving out the uniform number, that is always first). e.g.

PlayerStats could be

```
11 p3 a12 r5 //uniform 11, 3 points 12 assists 5 rebounds
//other info
```

OR

```
   11 p    3 r  5  a      12 //same exact values
```

### What I've come up with

---

can't seem to think of an algorithm to grab these values from the file in the correct order, i was thinking of something along these lines:

```
inFile << tmp.uniform; //uniform is ALWAYS first
getline(inFile,str);  //get the remaining line
int i = 0;
while(str[i] == " ") //keep going until i find something that isnt space
    i++;

if(str[i] == 'p')  //heres where i get stuck, how do i find that number now?

else if(str[i] == 'a')

eles if(str[i] = 'r'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only going to check one letter, you could use a `switch` statement instead of `if / else`, that would make it easier to read.

You know where the number starts at that point, (hint: `str[i+1]`), so depending on what type your `str[]` is, you can either use `atoi` if its a char array, or `std::stringstream` if it's an `std::string`.

I'm tempted to give you some code, but you said not too. If you do want some, let me know and I'll edit the answer with some code.

Instead of using a 'merge' function, try using an `std::vector` so you can just `push_back` your structure instead of doing any 'merging'. Besides, your merge function is basically a [copy assignment operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_%28C%2B%2B%29), which is created by the compiler by default (you don't need to create a 'merge' function), you just need to use `=` to copy the data across. If you wanted to do something special in your 'merge' function, then you should [overload the copy assignment operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_%28C%2B%2B%29#Overloading_copy_assignment_operator) instead of a 'merge' function. Simples.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like that:

```
int readNumber () {
  while isdigit (nextchar) -> collect in numberstring or directly build number
  return that number;
}
lineEater () {
  Read line
  skip over spaces
  uniform=readNumber ();
  haveNum=false;
  haveWhat=false;
  Loop until eol {
    skip over spaces
    if (isdigit)
      number=readNumber ();
      skip over spaces
      haveNum=true;
    else 
      char=nextChar;
      haveWhat=true;
    if (haveChar and haveNum) {
      switch (char) {
        case 'p' : points=number; break;
        ...
      }
      haveNum=false;
      haveWhat=false;
    }
  }
```

or, if you are more ambitous, write a grammar for your input and use lex/yacc.